# 10 Ether within 50 minutes

Tags: mining, ether, solo-mining

I'm new to Ethereum. I started learning like a few days ago, so this might be a very stupid question!

I started mining with my gaming pc. It has a hashrate of 25 MH/s. I started mining with a balance of 0 ether. I checked my balance after 50 minutes of mining and it said '10.00 ether' which is (at the time of writing this) as far I understand 2169.10 USD. This is a huge amount of money for 50 minutes of mining.

This seems waaay to good to be true so I'm pretty sure I'm not understanding something. Can someone explain how this is possible?

Maybe someone accidentally sent Ether to the wrong address?

[image]

From Ethereum wallet:

[image: Ethereum wallet]

Comment: Easy way is to verify the balance in [etherscan.io](http://etherscan.io)

Comment: To original poster: You've checked the wrong answer as being correct. Much more likely that you were mining on the testnet. If that is correct, you should uncheck the currently checked answer and check the right one. You don't want others who might have the same problem to be confused.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first thing to check is if the node you are working on is synced.  If it is not synced, it will let your mine old blocks and you'r balance will grow untill yout get synced.  It then zero's yout out....  one clue is that there is no gas additions to your mining rewards.

In the same screen as the checkBalance comand, try...

> eth.syncing

If the current block equals the highest block, then you are synced and that is not your problem... otherwise you need to get synced.

Comment: Hi Richard. I'm just wondering if you can provide some citation where you learned that what you say is happening is happening? I'm not saying it isn't correct, just that I've never heard of a syncing node mining old blocks and those rewards appearing for a time and then disappearing when the node is synced. Not saying it doesn't happen, just wondering if you have some citation of this. If not, then I think the other answer to this question is probably more likely. (Apparently others think this as well which is why that other answer has more upvotes.)

Comment: Reality is likely more complicated than my explanation. I was syncing my first geth node when exactly this had happened to me. I was also searching for mining software and running them at the same time. The version number of ethminer was pre 0.9.41 but its deleted and I don't remember which one. Geth was version 1.3.3. With Geth syncing I started ethminer and it downloaded a DAG and started mining.  I let it run for a few hours and it was solving about 1 block per hour.  The balance zeroed itself once the node was synced.  Its a toss up as to what caused the issue as I don't have diagnostics.

Answer (score 9):

You are most likely mining on some test-net or your own private network.
similar discussion here: https://forum.ethereum.org/discussion/5569/am-i-mining